# Simple way to toggle a button's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Like the title says I'd like the user to click the button and get a new value. In this case it is a button to toggle a menu from hidden to visible and back and forth. Here is my code.

I want it to say "show menu" and "hide menu"

Right now I click, menu opens and new value is set and menu can close but the value doesn't go back.

jquery:

```
$(function () {   
$("#UIcontainer").hide();

$("#button").click(function() {
$("#UIcontainer").toggle( function() {
    $("#button").val('hide menu');
});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {   
    $("#UIcontainer").hide();

    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        $("#UIcontainer").toggle();
        this.value = this.value == 'hide menu' ? 'show menu' : 'hide menu';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gv3vw/1/)

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in the very last line? Also I wrote a little if else statement that worked but I see how yours is more fool proof. Thanks!

Comment: The last line is a ternary statement, and just like an if/else statement it sets the value based on what the value currently is, with just plain javascript, no jQuery !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(function () {   
$("#UIcontainer").hide();

$("#button").click(function() {
$("#UIcontainer").toggle();
$(this).val($(this).val() == "hide menu" ? "show menu" : "hide menu");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working as charm

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="hide menu" />
<div id='UIcontainer'>fladfl</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val=="hide menu") {
            $("#button").val('show menu');
        } else {
            $("#button").val('hide menu');  
        }
        $("#UIcontainer").toggle();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be like this. set an attribute to your button. for example toggle.

```
<input type="button" toggle="show">


$(function () {   

    $("#button").click(function() {
        if ($this.attr("toggle")=="show"){
            $("#UIcontainer").show();
            $this.attr("toggle")="hide"
        }
        else{
            $("#UIcontainer").hide();
            $this.attr("toggle")="show"
        }
    });

});
```